# What does “spans a continuum” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does “spans a continuum” mean “creates a bridge” in this sentence - “As the chart indicates, creating spans a continuum from adding to inventing.”?

Answer (score 3):

"Creates a bridge" is accurate, in a sense, but it may not be the most useful way to interpret that phrase.

**A 'continuum' implies that there is an infinite number of variations on something, ranging between two quite different extremes.** The shades of grey form a continuum between white and black: the two are opposites, but you can create a line which changes smoothly from one into the other by running through the intermediate shades without ever making a dramatic change. Each point on the line is nearly the same as the points on either side, and for any possible combination of black and white, there's a point on the line that corresponds to it.

Similarly, "a continuum from adding to inventing" means that there are an enormous number of possible activities, ranging from purely 'adding' at one end to purely 'inventing' at the other with all of the possible combinations of partially-adding-and-partially-inventing falling somewhere in between the two extremes.

**To 'span a/the continuum' then means to 'include everything that falls anywhere on the specified continuum'.**

In this case, that means that 'creating' includes things that are 'adding', things that are 'inventing', and all of the things that are some combination of the two extremes.

Answer (score 0):

Beginning:

> SPAN
>
> verb
>
> 1.(of a bridge, arch, etc.) extend from side to side of; connect.

End:

> CONTINUUM
>
> NOUN
>
> 1.a continuous sequence in which adjacent elements are not perceptibly different from each other, although the extremes are quite distinct

*Create a bridge* is a fair assessment of the phrase, while *Connecting* also fits the meaning.

It may be personal preference, but I have always heard it (and refer to it myself) as: *Spanning **the** continuum*. We are talking about *definite* things on a chart, not nebulous ideas, so the definite article definitely applies.

Comment: Create a bridge is not the right interpretation. "Span the continuum" means it covers everything from a to z without breaks or gaps. A bridge covers a gap. So: Extend from adding to inventing in a continuous sequence.